# How can I create table (sql) in python with for loop?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to create a lot of sql table?
I think this, for exmaple:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()
for x in range(0, 100):
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE tableX (id real, name text,price real)''')
```

and `X` is in range:
`X: 0,1,.....,100`

Comment: You can do it, but it looks like a wrong database design. If you start numbering your variables or tables you do something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()
for x in range(0, 100):
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE table%s (id real, name text,price real)'''%x)
```